# Braces in GNU APL

Tags: function, apl

I am using **`GNU APL 1.1 (svn 4460)`** on Linux `2.6.32` and I have some problems with function definitions.

This snippet works as expected:

```
∇R←ODD N
R←2|N
∇

(ODD L)/L←⍳10
```

But when I try this

```
{2|⍵} 5
```

or this

```
ODD←{2|⍵}
```

I get a syntax error. The same snippets run fine [here](http://www.tryapl.org/).

I am a complete beginner to APL. Could anyone explain me what causes this syntax error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You first example uses conventional APL "del" notation to define a function. The second two examples use direct definition (commonly known as dfns - pronounced dee-funs) which is an extension by Dyalog APL, and obviously does not run in the interpreter you are using. The ease of defining functions this way is a great advantage.

Comment: Thank you very much. Which interpreter would you recommend for a person who works on a Linux box and wants to take a look into APL. I found that there is a Dyalog Personal Edition for Linux, but I couldn't find the download. Then there is NARS2000, but apparently this is only for windows? How can I get started with APL?

Comment: I would definitely go with Dyalog. Their web site is not as good as their product... I would just email them about how to get a Linux version.

Comment: This feature is coming to GNU APL, but it's not available yet.

Answer (score 2):

The dfns (function fragment in curly braces) syntax is not supported by all APLs.  If it's not supported, expect a syntax error or nonce error.

To my knowledge, only Dyalog APL and NGN APL (see http://ngn.github.io/apl/web/) support it.

Sharp APL had a direct definition feature but the syntax was rather different.

NGN APL does not support legacy function definition, only dfns.

Answer (score 2):

GNU APL has now a support for such dfns; you can try it by compiling it from the subversion repository or wait for the release 1.3.